# ngx-translate switches to default language after refreshing the page

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

I have two buttons and setlang function switches the languages (Either to DE or ENG). When I switch the languages, the code works and I am able to switch my languages in various sections.

**Problem:**

When I refresh the page, the language is switched back to the default one.

I am not sure, where to change the code, so that my previously selected language is retained.

**What I tried?**

I tried to set language at various places, but was not able to achieve the required result, as I am new in angular, maybe I am not doing it correctly.

**app.module.ts:**

```
export function setupTranslateFactory(
  service: TranslateService): Function {
  return () => service.use('de');
}
```

**component.ts:**

```
export class LanguageSelectionComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input('isGerman') isGerman: boolean;

  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {  


  }

  ngOnInit() {


  }
  setLang(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang);

  }

}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <button (click)="setLang('de')">DE</button>

    <button (click)="setLang('en')">EN</button>
</div>
```

Comment: There's no built-in storage in `ngx-translate`, says the community forums. Therefore you might use `localStorage` or maybe a library like [@ngx-pwa/local-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage) to keep the latest value

Answer (score 1):

You should save selected language in `localStorage`, and then in each loading check this value in `localStorage`.

As an alternative you can use language in your url path, for example by using `localize-router` library for `ngx-translate` - library and description is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/localize-router

In this way you doesn't need to keep lang in your `LocalStorage` or `cookie` because you have always access to this lang from `localize-router` service.